# ImageIcon method loops infinitely

Tags: java, swing, imageicon

I'm working on an Java swing application where I'm trying to load the images for the pieces for chess figures, and all have worked very good until suddenly, I got the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.base/java.lang.String.indexOf(String.java:1612)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.indexOf(String.java:1569)
    at java.base/java.net.URLStreamHandler.parseURL(URLStreamHandler.java:151)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.file.Handler.parseURL(Handler.java:67)
    at java.base/java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:696)
    at java.base/java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:563)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath$FileLoader.getResource(URLClassPath.java:1222)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath$FileLoader.findResource(URLClassPath.java:1211)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath.findResource(URLClassPath.java:294)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findResourceOnClassPath(BuiltinClassLoader.java:499)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findResource(BuiltinClassLoader.java:323)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.getResource(ClassLoader.java:1400)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getResource(Class.java:2741)
    at model.Board.getImageIcon(Board.java:246)
    at model.Board.setBoard(Board.java:49)
    at model.Board.<init>(Board.java:37)
    at model.Board.getBoardInstance(Board.java:28)
    at controler.FigureAction.<init>(FigureAction.java:15)
    at model.Figure.<init>(Figure.java:30)
at model.Board.setBoard(Board.java:49)
at model.Board.<init>(Board.java:37)
at model.Board.getBoardInstance(Board.java:28)
at controler.FigureAction.<init>(FigureAction.java:15)
at model.Figure.<init>(Figure.java:30)
at model.Board.setBoard(Board.java:49)
at model.Board.<init>(Board.java:37)
at model.Board.getBoardInstance(Board.java:28)
at controler.FigureAction.<init>(FigureAction.java:15)
at model.Figure.<init>(Figure.java:30)
at model.Board.setBoard(Board.java:49)
at model.Board.<init>(Board.java:37)
at model.Board.getBoardInstance(Board.java:28)
at controler.FigureAction.<init>(FigureAction.java:15)
at model.Figure.<init>(Figure.java:30)
at model.Board.setBoard(Board.java:49)
at model.Board.<init>(Board.java:37)
at model.Board.getBoardInstance(Board.java:28)
at controler.FigureAction.<init>(FigureAction.java:15)
at model.Figure.<init>(Figure.java:30)
at model.Board.setBoard(Board.java:49)
at model.Board.<init>(Board.java:37)
at model.Board.getBoardInstance(Board.java:28)
at controler.FigureAction.<init>(FigureAction.java:15)
at model.Figure.<init>(Figure.java:30)at model.Board.setBoard(Board.java:49)
at model.Board.<init>(Board.java:37)
at model.Board.getBoardInstance(Board.java:28)
at controler.FigureAction.<init>(FigureAction.java:15)
at model.Figure.<init>(Figure.java:30)
at model.Board.setBoard(Board.java:49)
at model.Board.<init>(Board.java:37)
at model.Board.getBoardInstance(Board.java:28)
at controler.FigureAction.<init>(FigureAction.java:15)
at model.Figure.<init>(Figure.java:30)
at model.Board.setBoard(Board.java:49)
at model.Board.<init>(Board.java:37)
at model.Board.getBoardInstance(Board.java:28)
at controler.FigureAction.<init>(FigureAction.java:15)
at model.Figure.<init>(Figure.java:30)
at model.Board.setBoard(Board.java:49)
at model.Board.<init>(Board.java:37)
at model.Board.getBoardInstance(Board.java:28)
at controler.FigureAction.<init>(FigureAction.java:15)
at model.Figure.<init>(Figure.java:30)
at model.Board.setBoard(Board.java:49)
at model.Board.<init>(Board.java:37)
at model.Board.getBoardInstance(Board.java:28)
at controler.FigureAction.<init>(FigureAction.java:15)
at model.Figure.<init>(Figure.java:30)
```

and the part from `at model.Board.setBoard(Board.java:49)` is logged many more times after (only that part).
While debugging the error, I saw that it enters the same method over and over until Stack overflow error occurs. There I'm retrieving the image from a local address.(it all have worked previously..)
Method is following:

```
private ImageIcon getImageIcon(String path,String description) {
        URL imgURL = getClass().getResource(path);
        if (imgURL != null) {
            Image ii=new ImageIcon(imgURL, description).getImage().getScaledInstance(70, 70, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
            ImageIcon im=new ImageIcon(ii);
            return im;

        } 
        else {
            System.err.println("Couldn't find file: " + path);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

and it is called here

```
public void setBoard(Color c1,Color c2,Dimension dim) {

        for(int i=0;i<8;i++) {
            for(int j=0;j<8;j++) {
                Point point=new Point(i,j);
                if ((i+j)%2==0) {
                    if(i==0 && j==0) {
                        ***Figure f=new Figure (null,null,"white_rook",null,getImageIcon("/images/WhiteRook.png",null));***
                        fields[i][j]=new Field(c1,new Position(point.x,point.y),i*8+j,f);
                        f.field=fields[i][j];
                        f.pos=new Position(point.x,point.y);
                        fields[i][j].add(f);
                        figures[i][j]=f;
                    }
```

which is part of method setBoard, which basically places each piece on the field. Figure class looks like:

```
public class Figure extends JPanel {

    public Field field;
    public Color color;
    public String name;
    public Movement movement;
    public ImageIcon imageIcon;
    public Position pos;

    public Figure(Field field, Color color, String name, Movement movement, ImageIcon icon) {
        this.field = field;
        this.color = color;
        this.name = name;
        this.movement = movement;
        this.imageIcon = icon;
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(70, 70));
        this.addMouseMotionListener(new FigureAction());
        this.addMouseListener(new FigureAction());
        this.setBackground(null);


    }
}
```

Here I'm making scaled imageIcon from the png image and retrieving it back. I would be very grateful if someone is able to tell me what could be the problem. I think I'm missing something important here, but currently don't know where else to look at.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the value of `path` when this call is made?  Does the entire stack trace show `model.Board.getImageIcon` more than once?

Comment: _While debugging the error, I saw that it enters the same method over and over_ Which method is being entered over and over? And who is calling this method over and over?

Comment: @VGR model.Board.getImageIcon is showed only once, but several lines after that are showed many times after (i rewrote stack trace above).. value of path is "/images/WhiteRook.png", it is correct path..

Comment: @Abra I marked method where getImageIcon is called with three asterisks.

Comment: Please add another 20–30 lines of stack trace, so we can get an idea of where the infinite method calls are coming from.

Comment: Looks like `FigureAction` constructor calls `setBoard()` which calls `Figure` constructor, which calls `FigureAction` constructor. Hence a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your stack trace and code provided:

```
at model.Board.setBoard(Board.java:49)
at model.Board.<init>(Board.java:37)
at model.Board.getBoardInstance(Board.java:28)
at controler.FigureAction.<init>(FigureAction.java:15)
at model.Figure.<init>(Figure.java:30)
```

which means:

1. `Figure` constructor is called.
2. Then `FigureAction` constructor is called.
3. Then, at some point after, `Board.setBoard` is called.
4. But `Board.setBoard` calls again the `Figure` constructor in the line you just highlighted with 3 asterisks...

In order to solve this, it depends on what you are trying to achieve. Which means we need even more code to see (for example an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)), if you want us to try and solve it.

Answer (score 2):

First `getClass()` could actually be a child class, so for good order:

```
    URL imgURL = Board.class.getResource(path);
```

Then, optimize memory usage & speed. I ignore description here.

```
Map<String, ImageIcon> sharedIcons = new HashMap<>();

private ImageIcon getImageIcon(String path, String description) {
    ImageIcon icon = sharedIcons.get(path);
    if (icon == null) {
        URL imgURL = getClass().getResource(path);
        if (imgURL == null) {
            System.err.println("Couldn't find file: " + path);
            return null;
        }
        icon = new ImageIcon(imgURL, description);
        Image ii = new ImageIcon(imgURL, description)
                .getImage().getScaledInstance(70, 70, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        icon = new ImageIcon(ii);

        sharedIcons.put(path, icon);
    }
    return icon;
}
```

The check that there is no recursion. `FigureAction` calling `setBoard` or so.